# Windows 7 network path not found without trailing backslash

Tags: networking, windows-7, network-share

I've run into a bit of an odd issue, one of the netbooks we've been working on seems to be having an issue with network paths. The machine is running Windows 7 Starter. If I try to run the following:

```
\\server\fd
```

I am greeted with an error:

```
0x80070035 Network path not found.
```

However if I type:

```
\\server\fd\
```

Everything is fine and the share opens as expected. (Note trailing backslash)
Any ideas what might be causing this to happen?

Comment: Funnily enough, I am facing the opposite issue on Windows 7 HP 64-bit. It will _not_ work with the trailing backslash, but will work without it. I would just chalk it up to Windows being Windows ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An old post, but I will post my findings here as a reference for others experiencing this problem.

I have found two possible causes for this:

One is described in http://forum.sysinternals.com/curious-windows-7-issue-connecting-to-unc_topic25113.html and has to do with the registry settings

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider
"ProviderOrder"="LanmanWorkstation,RDPNP"
"ProviderOrder"="LanmanWorkstation,RDPNP"
```

The above should be the correct setting.

The other cause I found by comparing a broken and working pc in our environement.
Working pc's had the registry setting

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
FileNotFoundCacheLifetime = 0
DirectoryCacheLifetime = 0
```

setting these (and more specificly DirectoryCacheLifetime) fixed the problem on a machine not working before.

Comment: While I was unable to follow up on this, I'm accepting this answer since it seems to be the most likely solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install or un-install any hardware or software on your netbook recently? Third Party applications can also cause this issue.
You can perform clean boot on your computer, to check whether any third party application is causing this issue. You can get more details on this issue and steps to perform clean boot [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/home-network-issue-0x80070035-network-path-not/f7ee3015-f487-45ef-9702-d1386ed66779)